# Microsoft access creating form

Tags: ms-access-2010

For example, I got the stamp duty band from £0 to £125000 with the rate is 1%, then I will type in the text box is £25000, what can I do so that the rate will appear 1% automatically?

Comment: Please provide us with more info.  WHERE do you want the 1% to show? Please explain WHAT your calculation is supposed to be (I see no relationship between 125000, 25000 and 1%). Thank you.

Comment: I got 2 text boxes, 1 is price, and 1 is rate, and when I type £25000 in price, it will show 1% in the rate box

Answer (score 0):

Use the following - change the field names as needed:

```
Private Sub txtAmt_AfterUpdate()
    Me.txtPct = Format(CDbl(Me.txtAmt) / 100, percent)
End Sub
```